# Why Metadata _id and _rev in Values?

Tags: mysql, json, couchdb

New to CouchDB after years of MySQL. Why am I getting metadata _id and _rev in the values map in a view the returns all records? Here's my view:

```
"views": "{
    "all": "{
        "map": "function (doc) {
            emit(doc.date, doc)
        }"
    }"
}"
```

When I query /database/_design/id/_view/all I get the following JSON:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"b77bbd5ab73b809ca830fe4b6900506f","key":"[2013, 09, 21, 00, 00, 00]","value":{"_id":"b77bbd5ab73b809ca830fe4b6900506f","_rev":"11-b134dfe46f86c96b4f7e2cf0abb13b61","location":"Mesuk Market","product":"Traditional Pork Skewer","total_items":550,"created_at":"[2013, 09, 21, 23, 24, 06]","date":"[2013, 09, 21, 00, 00, 00]"}},
{"id":"b77bbd5ab73b809ca830fe4b69005f1e","key":"[2013, 09, 21, 00, 00, 00]","value":{"_id":"b77bbd5ab73b809ca830fe4b69005f1e","_rev":"2-ee4e464cdf5de23563c0cc6b62bc4b07","date":"[2013, 09, 21, 00, 00, 00]","created_at":"[2013, 09, 21, 23, 27, 00]","total_items":100,"product":"All Meat Skewer","location":"Mesuk Market"}}
]}
```

Why am I getting _id and _rev in the map of values? The docs [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Creating_Views) (and several other places) don't show those fields in the values.

This isn't really blocking my work on a project, but I don't understand why it's happening. Is it from the way I'm setting up my view or making a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_id` and `_rev` are [special document fields](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Special_Fields):

- `_id` is database-wide unique Document ID
- `_rev` is [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) token

Comment: Great, thanks for the links. That makes sense, but I'm still not clear why I'm getting them in my values when none of the CouchDB docs show JSON returns with those fields in the values. Guess I won't worry about it, relegating the discontinuity to yet another instance of docs not matching reality.

Answer (score 3):

The **_id** and **_rev** values are needed to CouchDB. The first one, **_id** (*uuid*), has to ensure uniqueness of the document in the database, the second one, **_rev** (*revision*), has to ensure there are no conflicts while multiple processes try to edit the same document.

These fields are **mandatory**.

**_id** is assigned by CouchDB when it's not in the document we try to create, **_rev** is always assigned by CouchDB.

Comment: `_rev` is not neccesarily assigned by couchdb.  You can place a document in a couchd database, so long as you include in the request `new_edits=false` in the url, and also provide a valid `_rev`, couchdb will honor your request to store the document with the given rev.  This is mainly useful for explicitly introducing conflicts in CouchDB.  (see here for more details: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API?highlight=%28new_edits%29)